# JEdit fails to log in with com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel

Tags: sftp, jedit

I am using [Jedit](http://www.jedit.org/) to remotely edit files on a Linux server, via the [ftp](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugindoc/FTP/) plugin. I am using sftp with password authentication.

Up until today it was working fine, but all of a sudden it is now displaying the following error every time I try to log in:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
```

This error is also visible in the sshd log file on the server.

I can log in via ssh using eg. putty with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that I had added a line to one of my bash profile scripts on the server which was echoing text every time I logged in, like this:

```
export PGVERSION=9.6
echo "PGVERSION=$PGVERSION"
```

The additional text was confusing the JEdit sftp plugin.

The solution was to ensure that the text was not echoed unless talking to a terminal, so I changed the second line above to:

```
[ -t 0 ] && echo "PGVERSION=$PGVERSION"
```